# AS3 mp3 Object in an array and retrieving and playing them help please New to AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, audio, import

Hi there i am new to as3 and i am not sure i am writing it properly.

i have a 10 sound variables that are linked to the mp3.
i also have an songArray.
and i have 10 buttons that are pushing the mp3 into the array
and the play button just tracing the songArray but i don't know how to continue and to be able to play the mp3 in the same sequence that they entered into the array.

```
package {

import C1.mp3;
import C2.mp3;
import C3.mp3;
import C4.mp3;
import C5.mp3;
import C6.mp3;
import C7.mp3;
import C8.mp3;
import C9.mp3;
import C10.mp3;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;


public class Main extends Sprite {



    private var master:Master = new Master();

    private var sound2:Sound = new C2.mp3();
    private var sound3:Sound = new C3.mp3();
    private var sound4:Sound = new C4.mp3();
    private var sound5:Sound = new C5.mp3();
    private var sound6:Sound = new C6.mp3();
    private var sound7:Sound = new C7.mp3();
    private var sound8:Sound = new C8.mp3();
    private var sound9:Sound = new C9.mp3();
    private var sound10:Sound = new C10.mp3();

    private var soundArray:Array = [];

    public function Main() {

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        init();

    }

    private function init():void {
        addChild(master);

        master.btn1.btnText.text = "A";
        master.btn2.btnText.text = "2";
        master.btn3.btnText.text = "3";
        master.btn4.btnText.text = "4";
        master.btn5.btnText.text = "5";
        master.btn6.btnText.text = "6";
        master.btn7.btnText.text = "7";
        master.btn8.btnText.text = "8";
        master.btn9.btnText.text = "9";
        master.btn10.btnText.text = "10";

        master.btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.btn10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);

        master.clearBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
        master.playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);

    }

    private function btnClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {

        switch (event.currentTarget.name){

            case "btn1":
                trace("1");
                    //sound1.play();
                    soundArray.push(sound1);
                break;

            case "btn2":
                trace("2");
                    //sound2.play();
                    soundArray.push(sound2);
                break;

            case "btn3":
                trace("3");
                    soundArray.push(sound3);
                break;

            case "btn4":
                trace("4");
                    soundArray.push(sound4);
                break;

            case "btn5":
                trace("5");
                    soundArray.push(sound5);
                break;

            case "btn6":
                trace("6");
                    soundArray.push(sound6);
                break;

            case "btn7":
                trace("7");
                    soundArray.push(sound7);
                break;

            case "btn8":
                trace("8");
                    soundArray.push(sound8);
                break;

            case "btn9":
                trace("9");
                    soundArray.push(sound9);
                break;

            case "btn10":
                trace("10");
                    soundArray.push(sound10);
                break;

        }

    }

    private function clearHandler():void {
        // Clean the soundArray back to empty.
        soundArray.splice(0);

    }

    private function playHandler():void{

        trace(soundArray);
    }



}
}
```

Comment: The code here is pretty ugly, why not use `for` loop?

Comment: Im new to coding im not sure how to retrieve the information

Comment: Hi Tim how would you write ?

Comment: So, what's your code working for? Click the button and play the right sound?

Comment: yes pretty much but let says the person clicks C1 and C4 after that C8 then play it will play in that order one after the other

Comment: Do you mean player click C1 and immediately click C4, if the sound1 is not finished yet, the sound4 should wait for sound1 finish?

Comment: yes its like making a phrase the sounds are words and i want the user to be able to make a phrase then send the phrase to play all the words one after the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **code clean**

1. Push the sound to array previously, and new a `Dictionary`, and new a `Vector` for play list.

   ```
   private var soundArray:Array = [ null, sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4, sound5, sound6, sound7, sound8, sound9, sound10 ];
   private var soundDic:Dictionary = new Dictionary;
   private var playList:Vector.<Sound> = new Vector.<Sound>;

   private static const MAX_BTN_NUM:uint = 10;
   ```
2. Use a `for loop` to init.

   ```
       for(var i:int = 1; i <= MAX_BTN_NUM; i++)
       {
           master["btn"+i].btnText.text = i+"";
           master["btn"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
           soundDic["btn"+i] = soundArray[i];
       }
   ```
3. Use `key-value` for btnClicked.

   ```
   private function btnClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
       playList.push( soundDic[event.currentTarget.name] );
   }
   ```

### **play one by one**

1. init a `int` for `clearInterval`

   ```
   private var tidx:int = -1;
   ```
2. the play one by one logic

   ```
   private function playOneByOne( sounds:Vector.<Sound>, idx:uint = 0 ):void{
       clearInterval( tidx );
       if( idx < sounds.length ){
           (sounds[idx] as Sound).play();
           tidx = setInterval( playOneByOne, (sounds[idx] as Sound).length, sounds, idx + 1 );
       }
   }
   ```

### **handle play and clear**

```
    private function clearHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void {
        playList.splice( 0, playList.length );
    }

    private function playHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void{
        playOneByOne( playList );
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it right now thanks i never used Dictionary im going to read up on that thank you very much ill let you know if it worked.

Comment: Hey Tim it works perfectly just one thing If i wanted to concatenate the mp3 for example i wanted sound3 and 5 and 6 then play them one after the other. how would i achieve that?

Comment: the btnClicked function doesn't play the mp3 i used that to push them into an array i have a playbtnfunction that i would wanted to play the sequenced mp3's

Comment: @SharonShalomIluz Updated, might have bugs.

Comment: Wow kinda to complicated for me. What i was really looking for is storing the sounds then using the playbtn function to play them one by one

Comment: @SharonShalomIluz I think I gotcha what you mean. You mean the player can click those buttons, and not play sound immediately, play a sound array which in a sequence that the button clicked **after a while**?

Comment: yes the user clicked the sound button as many as he wants. it is not playing the sound but storing them somewhere. the by pressing the playbtn will play the sound that he stored. the same way he had pressed. this is why i tried putting the sound mp3 in an array with the push property but i couldn't get it to play

Comment: @SharonShalomIluz So, check this out.

Comment: im assuming the playList is an Array right ? if so its still not working

Comment: @SharonShalomIluz I find a bug in playOneByOne, see my update. It's ok now, I tested. If you still can't get it working, show me your whole code.

Comment: Yeh Yeah its working thank you so much Tim wow. Now i got some studying to do. Thanks a lot